# php simulating form submit

Tags: php, forms, http-headers, form-submit

Can I simulate or "fake" form submit action by sending same headers to server like browser do? I'm not sure if it is need to send something else except of headers.
Where can I see which headers were sent by browser and how to send them with PHP?
Thank you.

Comment: You can see headers sent by browser in a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cURL for this porpose. cURL example using php, you can see here.

For POST request http://beamtic.com/curl-http-post-requests

For GET request http://beamtic.com/curl-http-get-request

Comment: Thanks a lot for a tutorial link. I solved the problem. Thanks again!